# ColdFusion - Return data of queryExecute and not the entire query

Tags: coldfusion, commandbox

So I'd like to return the value of a property of a table only, not the entire query using coldfusion and my local table.
This is how I display it:

```
<h3 class="queue-type-label">#match.outcome.queueDescription.toString()#</h3>
```

Also, this is how I defined queueDescription:

```
outcome.queueDescription = queryExecute("select Description from Queues_de where ID='#match.queueId#'");
```

I get only the following result:
[image]

But I'd really like to get just the "Description" value... (Solo/Duo (Rangliste)) such stuff you know.
Does any1 can help me?! :O

Comment: Use this. `match.outcome.queueDescription.Description`. When you are using `toString` it is just doing serialization of the complex query.

Comment: Trick of the day: use writeDump(var=varName) or <cfdump var=“#varName#”> to look at variables in ColdFusion.